# jQuery - Target ASP control by generated Name Attribute

Tags: html, asp.net, dom

I need to reference an ASP control, through JavaScript.  I tried using the ID that is generated for the control, but it wasn't working.  Referencing the control by the generated "Name" works, though.

ASP

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkMyself" runat="server" Text="Search" />
```

HTML

```
<input id="ctl00_CenterMainContentPanel_wndStudentList_C_SearchUC1_chkMyself" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CenterMainContentPanel$wndStudentList$C$SearchUC1$chkMyself">
```

What are the drawbacks of referencing by Name.  Is this generated Name always going to be the same?

Comment: I think you need to clarify "referencing" context - from client script or server side? DOM element `id` and/or `name` vs. `Control.Id` server side. See [ASP.NET Web Server Control Identification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1d04y8ss(v=vs.100).aspx). Hth.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  And I only need to reference the control client side.

Comment: The link should explain/answer things better than I can :) Additionally, you can do something like this `<input type="text" name="bar" runat="server" />` - which, if memory serves, is called "HTML server controls". Hth...

Answer (score 0):

Writing selectors is different for ASP.NET controls since they're rendered differently in HTML on the page.  There's 2 recommended ways of doing this.

**This (recommended)**

I usually use `ClientIDMode="Static"`.  I can then write a selector as usual, like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkMyself" runat="server" Text="Search" />

$('#chkMyself");
```

**Or this**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkMyself" runat="server" Text="Search" />

$('#<%= chkMyself.ClientID %>')
```

But the above jquery will only work in the same aspx file.  Will not work in a separate JS file.